# Is there a built-in way to count records in a SQLite table?

Tags: sql, sqlite, aggregate-functions

I'm looking for something "a little bit faster" than doing SELECT * FROM table_name and stepping through all the records...

Comment: Awesome thing is all the answers below will work correctly on *any* ANSI SQL database :p (It will be *much* faster in all but the most trivial situations.)

Comment: Well, you mean to get the number of records I need to fetch all of them? Is there a meta tag or something to do it faster? And if not, what about SELECT COUNT(1) FROM table_name instead?

Comment: Was there any research done at all before this? Did you Google "SQL count" at all?

Comment: It's faster because the SQL engine can *throw away* records as it counts them. The `COUNT` aggregate requires either a column name or `*`. It doesn't make a difference which is chosen and thus most people choose `COUNT(*)`.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name
```

Jaw dropping, eh? :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the COUNT aggregate function:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS numRecords
  FROM YOUR_TABLE
```

I defined the column alias "numRecords" to make it easier to isolate the value you want to retrieve.

Answer (score 1):

Try `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name;`